# How to ignore the rest of a statement in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I have the following C-like document:

```
  //...
  some_var = 4 + 3;           // 1.
  another_var = some var + 2; // 2.
  yet_another_var = 42;       // 3.
  ;                           // 4.
  //...
```

and this grammar snippet:

```
block: statement+;
statement: assignment | empty_statement;
assignment: /* more assignment stuff */ ';';
empty_statement: ';';
```

Statement 2 contains an error; using DefaultErrorStrategy results in the parse tree seeing statement 2 with some modification to it in the parse tree. Instead, I'd like to report the error and then ignore the rest of the statement, treating it as if it were an `empty_statement`. Alternatively, is there some trick I can use in the grammar itself and/or the error strategy to bail on a single failing `statement` match when trying to process a `block`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following grammar:

```
block: statement+;
statement: assignment | empty_statement | error_alt;
assignment: /* more assignment stuff */ ';';
empty_statement: ';';
error_alt: ~';'+ ';'
```

During tree traversing, you can report a parsing error on every `error_alt`.

Comment: That was one of my initial thoughts, but by going through `error_alt` don't I lose the context of the original error? For example, if I had the C-like assignment
`foo = bar + + 3;` I want to report the error at the second `+` and not `foo`.